# Anaconda: Update Package Build Where Version is Same but Build is Different

Tags: anaconda

Is there a way to force update a package's build in Anaconda?I installed Caffe2 pre built binaries via Anaconda, and now I need to update it. The list command reveals the package name, version, build, and channel:

```
caffe2                    0.8.dev         py36_2018.05.05    caffe2
```

The package, according to Anaconda cloud is currently *still* version `0.8.dev`, but the *build* has been update (since May 5th), to `py36_2018.07.20`.If I run the update command:

```
conda update -n caffe2 -c caffe2  -f caffe2
```

The output is:

```
caffe2: 0.8.dev-py36_2018.05.05 caffe2 --> 0.8.dev-py36_2018.05.05 caffe2
```

Which is obviously not the newest build. I've found that if I create a *new* environment and do a fresh install of caffe2 then the console will confirm that I am installing the latest:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
caffe2-0.8.dev             |  py36_2018.07.20         8.4 MB  caffe2
```

How can I update the package **build** to the newest without having to create a new environment or uninstalling/reinstalling in this case where the version number is still the same?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I suspect what's happening is that conda doesn't know how to compare that build number (build numbers are usually integers) so it doesn't decide to update the package; however, when you create the new environment, it goes and gets the newest-uploaded package. As for how to fix it, I think probably uninstall and reinstall is your best bet. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @darthbith I was thinking similarly. No problem with uninstall/reinstall, I've tried and that does work. I just thought to ask if there was a best practice since it seems like a workaround. Also pretty obvious the package should be updating it's build/version number better.

Comment: You may also try fully specifying the build number as well, something like `conda install caffe=0.8.dev_py36_2018.07.20` (or however it's specified in an `environment.yml` file)

Comment: Good point, I'll check that out next time I get tired of reinstalling haha.